# php exec tar -cvf does not work in aws

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, exec, tar

I am trying to tar a folder in AWS EBS environment via php exec command.
I try to tar folder 170220 using the following command

```
exec("tar -cvf /var/app/current/ba/170220.tar  /var/app/current/ba/170220 ");
exec("gzip /var/app/current/ba/170220.tar ");
```

After 170220.tar.gz is created, I gunzip it and display the tar file content. But only one file is in the tar file.

```
tar -tvf 170220.tar
var/app/current/ba/170220/
var/app/current/ba/170220/C0401/
var/app/current/ba/170220/C0401/SRC/
var/app/current/ba/170220/C0401/SRC/SJ1.xml
```

There shall be two files in SJ1.xml, SJ2.xml in SRC folder. 
If I do the same thing manually in shell command of Amazon EC2, everything is OK. But when I run the script in php exec command, only one file is in the tar. 
What is the problem here ?

Comment: Maybe there's a permission problem? Try redirecting errors with `2>&1`, and capturing all the output into a variable.